# Injecting a registered named service is not working as expected using Autofac 4.2.1

Tags: c#, exception, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

**Background**

Autofac 4.2.1(tried with the latest version of Autofac and the issue is still present) ,
WebApi project .netcore 2.2
Issue :
I have two instances of the same service, which I register to the ContainerBuilder with Name:

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceOne>().Named<IService>("ServiceOne").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceTwo>().Named<IService>("ServiceTwo").SingleInstance();
```

I then inject the named services to my controller classes as required:

```
builder.Register(c => new KeysController(c.ResolveNamed<IService>("ServiceOne")));
builder.Register(c => new ValuesController(c.ResolveNamed<IService>("ServiceTwo")));
```

Autofac is not able to resolve the IService for both of my controllers by name.

**The Exception**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AutoFacNaming.IService' while attempting to activate
>   'AutoFacNaming.Controllers.ValuesController'.

Comment: Do you see an Inner Exception? it may contain the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ASP.net core will not build controller from the container but only its parameters. You can change this by specifying `AddControllersAsServices()` when you register MVC with the service collection. Doing that will automatically register controller types into the `IServiceCollection` when the service provider factory calls `builder.Populate(services)`.

```
public class Startup
{
  // Omitting extra stuff so you can see the important part...
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    // Add controllers as services so they'll be resolved.
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
  }

  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    // If you want to set up a controller for, say, property injection
    // you can override the controller registration after populating services.
    builder.Register(c => new KeysController(c.ResolveNamed<IService>("ServiceOne")));
    builder.Register(c => new ValuesController(c.ResolveNamed<IService>("ServiceTwo")));
  }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services)